# Laravel 5 Middleware Doesn't work

Tags: laravel, routes, kernel, middleware

I have problem with my custom middleware. It doesn't work. I have registered it in Kernel.php, only in $routeMiddleware. Here is my code:

```
/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'test' => \App\Http\Middleware\TestMiddleware::class

 ];
}
```

Here is my Controller Code:

```
/**
 * Middleware Activated
 */
public function __constructor()
{
    $this->middleware('test');
}
```

and here is my custom middleware code:

```
 protected $auth;
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!$this->auth->check())
    {
       return redirect('/');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

When I'm logout and type in url

> profile/21

it shows me the profile of user with id 21. I want to prevent that with middleware but it won't work for me.

Does anyone have an idea how to do that or where is the mistake?

Comment: my file looks like: 

/**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'test' => \App\Http\Middleware\TestMiddleware::class
    ];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure if the middleware gets triggered put something like `die('middleware triggerd');` inside the handle function of the middleware.

I noticed you have `function __constructor()` instead of `function __construct()`.
That might be the problem.

If it does trigger the middleware but you still have the same problem try replacing:
`if (!$this->auth->check())` with `if (!\Auth::check())`

Comment: I put dd() but it didn't trigger. I don't want to use it in routes file because I think is more elegant to use it in controller. I can't find where I'm wrong.
I have tried with Auth::check() but still doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe, but I use Route::resource('profile', 'ProfileController'); and I want to use only and except to use that middleware on specific functions.

Comment: @HerilMuratovic Glad to help!

Comment: I have the same problem, I had a field in the database, on the user model, called "is_admin" the middleware worked properly; however when I changed it to "role" it stopped working now it just allows anyone to the protected pages.